# Why is my code still being executed with python3.5?

Tags: python, python-3.x, linux, docker

I have a docker image for ubuntu 16.04 which I have to use for my project. This image contains python3.5 which is not supported anymore.

So, in my Dockerfile I remove python3.5 (user ROOT):

```
RUN update-alternatives --remove python /usr/bin/python3.5
```

Then I install python3.6 which works quite OK:

```
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y apt-transport-https && apt-get install build-essential -y

RUN apt-get install libssl-dev openssl -y &&\
    wget https://www.python.org/ftp/python/3.6.7/Python-3.6.7.tgz &&\
    tar xzvf Python-3.6.7.tgz &&\
    cd Python-3.6.7 &&\
    ./configure &&\
    make &&\
    make install
```

Furthermore, I install odbc-driver and a couple of other packages like: pytz and pyyaml:

```
RUN python3 -m pip install --upgrade pip &&\
python3 -m pip install requests urllib3&&\
python3 -m pip install pytz &&\
python3 -m pip install pyyaml &&\
apt install python3-pyodbc
```

Finally, I switch to a default user 1001 and then, using template of a colleague, enter this:

```
ENV ORDS=http://10.100.87.15:8080/ords/blabla
ENV PYTHONUNBUFFERED=TRUE
ENV PYTHONDONTWRITEBYTECODE=TRUE
ENV PATH="/opt:/opt/se:/opt/se/script:${PATH}"
ENV PYTHONPATH="${PYTHONPATH}:/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages"
```

Then I want to make sure I am using python3.6:

```
RUN alias python3='/usr/bin/python3.6'
```

And voila! My code is being executed with python3.5. Did I have to use  RUN update-alternatives in the end of the dockerfile? Dis I have to put alias, maybe, straight after the installation of python3.6?

Comment: "A standard docker image for ubuntu 16.04" - what image, exactly? I just pulled `ubuntu:xenial` and I see no Python 3.5 resident anywhere on it. Specify the image and tag precisely from Docker Hub or wherever you're pulling it.

Comment: Hey Brad, sorry for the missunderstanding. I meant "standard in my company"... I am correcting my question.

Comment: `RUN` executes its argument in a separate shell; the alias is defined and lost as soon as that shell exits.

Comment: Unluckily we can not offer support for your companies image for the simple reason that we don't have it and can not reproduce your issue. And BTW standard support for Ubuntu 16.04 ends in a couple of weeks.

Comment: @chepner you mean using alias makes no sence in this case? what could be the best alternative?

Comment: Yes, the alias makes no sense. I would have though using `update-alternatives` to disable or remove Python 3.5 to be the correct course of action; I'm not sure why that didn't work or how to correct that.